# xpath xml help any one?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-table

I want to get data from internet and I have been sucssful in parsing by HTML and now I need xpath to extact it from table. so I want to extract data from second row of second coulmn. How would I do that?I wrote this: `//table[1]/tr[10]/td[2]` but it doesn't show any thing

thanks

Comment: can u provide the structure of Html you need to traverse??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTML isn't XML, despite any similarities. That is why you can't normally parse HTML with an XML parser (which is necessary in order to use most XPath implementations).

One option would be to use something like [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) (Java), [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (Python) or a similar library for other platforms. These libraries allow HTML to be parsed as if it were XML, meaning that standard XML libraries can then be used to operate on the data (XPath, XSLT, DOM manipulation, SAX events, etc...)

Another option would be to try using something like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (with the `--html` and `--xmlout` options). This will convert the HTML to proper XML, allowing you to use any XML tools that you want.

Comment: You can parse HTML with a DOM parser though. Valid XHTML should be fine in an XML parser too. It's unclear from the question what they're using.

Comment: The type of XML parser (DOM, SAX, push, pull, etc...) has nothing to do with whether or not you can parse HTML. If it's not well-formed XML (and HTML is usually not) then you can't parse it with an XML parser. But XHTML *is* XML so you can parse it with any XML parser.

Comment: There are many DOM parsers around that can handle HTML just fine. PHP's DOMDocument as well as the one built into most JavaScript engines for example.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the second column of the second row of the first table (assumed from your question) be

```
//table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]
```

This doesn't take into account any `<th>` elements that may be present.

Really not sure why you're specifying the tenth row (`tr[10]`)